# PHP - Redirect with modified/removed referrer?

Tags: php, header, refresh, referrer

I'm assuming this is not possible but I'm going to ask anyway because there are a lot of people here who are a whole lot smarter than me!

I want to do a header redirect and spoof the referrer.

Here's why, I use a click tracking system to measure my traffic and marketing spends/ROI and I don't want to pass the original referrer to my destinations because I don't want other people seeing my top traffic sources and keywords... I also don't want to pass on traffic with a blank referrer (which is what I do now) because that looks like I'm being sneaky or wanting to trick someone, which is also not the case.

What I want to do is spoof the referrer value to my domain, but do this for ALL visits that pass through my tracking system. Basically, I want to show that the traffic is passing through my private tracking system but without giving up any detailed info!

Possible?

I know that referrer info is passed by browser and aside from a meta refresh I honestly can't think of any other method!!

Comment: Have you tried to add `header("Referer: http://your.url");` before `header("Location: http://your.redirect.url");`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. I think this is not possible to be honest, because the referrer is set by the browser and not the script (as far as I know)... but was hoping that someone might have an answer.